# Bluemix blockchain: How can i query out this?

Tags: post, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I need to know how to query the following invoke(AC(123456A)or (user_type1_c19a5f0b7e) when i have init this:

```
   {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "deploy",
        "params": {
            "type": 1,
            "chaincodeID": {
                "path": "https://github.com/johndoe/learn-chaincode/finished"
            },
            "ctorMsg": {
                "function": "init",
                "args": [
                    "hi there"
                ]
            },
            "secureContext": "user_type1_191b8c2993"
        },
        "id": 1
    }
```

Here is my (successful) invoke:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "invoke",
    "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID": {
            "name": "b42b506c13fg1157520d585841a691f4b598d9aac53adc95277ed710c7f1f5aaa59a89a8dca8ddf3e46d5241562f3316956a04ad8a33181d30cb01b1c4c9adb2f"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
            "function": "AC(123456A)",
            "args": [
               "AcctId:949392949233 ","Year2015 Sem1 ", "IT1234:A ", " IT2345:B+ ", "IT3456:A ", "Year 2015 Sem2 ", "IT4567:B ", "IT5678: B", "IT5678:A ","Year 2016 Sem1 ", "IT6789:C ", "IT7890:C ", "Cumulative GPA: 3"

            ]
        },
        "secureContext": "user_type1_c19a5f0b7e"
    },
    "id": 4
}
```

Here is the query that I am trying and I can't get the results that I want:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "query",
    "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID": {
            "name": "b42b506c13fg1157520d585841a691f4b598d9aac53adc95277ed710c7f1f5aaa59a89a8dca8ddf3e46d5241562f3316956a04ad8a33181d30cb01b1c4c9adb2f"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
            "function": "AC(123456A)",
            "args": [
               "AcctId:949392949233 "
            ]
        },
        "secureContext": "user_type1_c19a5f0b7e"
    },
    "id": 2
}
```

Here's the response for the query.

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "code": -32003,
    "message": "Query failure",
    "data": "Error when querying chaincode: Error:Transaction or query returned with failure: Received unknown function query"
  },
  "id": 2
}
```

Right now, I am trying out this tutorial, which is provided by IBM Bluemix: 
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode.

I have tried an init using their example and do invoke(successful) to suit my needs. I tried the Bluemix tutorial, which I mentioned earlier, and I am able to achieve what is stated in the documentation. Therefore, I decided to invoke something to suit my own needs. However, i am unable to query the person AC(123456A) or user_type1_c19a5f0b7e with showing of items such as "Year2015 Sem1", "IT1234:A", "IT3456:B+ " and etc . How can I query (the invoke) to suit my own needs?

Answer (score 0):

Our understanding is that you are using an IBM Blockchain Starter Developer Network on IBM Bluemix.  Using this environment, the "Learn Chaincode" tutorial (https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode) has been followed.  We would like to confirm our understanding of your results when following the tutorial.  Our understanding is that when following the tutorial, the Init, Invoke, and Query chaincode functions all operated as expected.  Is the understanding correct that the tutorial as written could be followed successfully?

Then we understand that the example chaincode was modified to apply different logic.  The Invoke for this modified chaincode that uses the AC(123456A) function with a user of user_type1_c19a5f0b7e appears to have been successful.  However, a query that also used the AC(123456A) function was not successful.  Is this understanding correct?

Could some additional details be provided so this can be considered further?

1. Did you write your own customized chaincode?  If so, could this chaincode (including the AC(123456A) function definition) be provided?
2. Is the AC(123456A) function located in the same Go source file as the rest of the chaincode?
3. We imagine that the user named user_type1_c19a5f0b7e was registered since the Invoke did work.  Were steps to register this user followed as noted in the "Secure Enrollment" section of the "Learn Chaincode" tutorial?
4. Can the AC(123456A) function both write values to the ledger (through the Invoke) and read values from the ledger (as is being attempted through the Query)?